# Loading Kotlin generated classes at runtime from Java

Tags: kotlin

I have 2 projects...

My main java project and a kotlin sub project that I moved some java classes out of the main project into and converted into kotlin.

I've configured the kotlin project to have a dependency on the main java project, it works quite well since IJ is constantly recompiling java classes in the main project.

But now that i've extracted classes from the Java project, it won't compile anymore of course - it needs to access the kotlin project.

However, I don't know how to do that.. can someone explain? thanks

my kotlin `out` folder is empty whenever I look at it

Comment: Why not put them all in one project with different folders for java (src/main/java) and kotlin (src/main/kotlin)?  It sounds like you have to. Circular dependencies are crazy.

Comment: analyzing my code, I realized that I just have to move a few more classes around... and then.. well, the kotlin project already accesses the Java project well enough for development of the kotlin project. And the java project actually will then only depend on the kotlin classes at runtime. They are not needed for development. That is because my java code is already loading those classes dynamically from the class names specified in xml files... So _as long as_ Class.forName() and Class<?>.getConstructor().getNewInstance() will work on Kotlin generate class files, then it will work out for me..

Comment: if anyone knows if that will work, please confirm.. I mean the last part about using in `java` `forName()` and `getNewInstance()` calling `Kotlin`-generated files

Comment: I recommend you go find out for yourself if it will work for your particular set of projects, dependencies, and architecture.  I don't think someone will chime in with an authoritative answer without knowing how you're doing things.  If you have a particular *problem* with a specific description, then people might have something to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin generates perfectly ordinary Java class files, so you can use `Class.forName()` and `Class<?>.getConstructor().getNewInstance()` with them just as well as with classes compiled from Java source code.